# Call to undefined method App\User::id() (View:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have created Custom Helper File **App/Helpers/Helper.php** for common functions, and I am trying to get data from the Helper class that I have created at Helper.php. Everything is fine when I call it in the blade file it shows an error **"BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\User::id()"**

**Helper.php**

```
<?php

use App\Cart;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

function totalCartItems()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id();
        $totalCartItems = Cart::where('user_id', $user_id)->sum('quantity');
    } else {
        $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
        $totalCartItems = Cart::where('session_id', $session_id)->sum('quantity');
    }
    return $totalCartItems;
}
```

Getting value at **cart.blade**

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Shopping Cart ({{ totalCartItems() }} item)</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
Auth::user()->id
```

or

```
Auth::id()
```

instead.

Comment: now i feel stupid. it's a field, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this

```php
Auth::check()
```

Use this

```php
if(Auth::user() !== null)
```